# Taiwan news in English with English dictionary

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, online-learning

I had read some Taiwanese articles in English and seen they had some of the English words with meaning of what the words meant at the bottom of the articles.

I tried to find the site again, but haven't been able to find it. I do get sites like https://international.thenewslens.com and https://www.taiwannews.com.tw/en/ which tell about developments in and around Taiwan as well as how they view the world, but I couldn't find the particular website. Does anybody know of such sites?

I may be traveling to Taiwan in the near future and want to have much information and understanding about Taiwan. If the sites which I described above are common, does it mean that the Taiwanese government is trying to have more English-speaking people?

Part of the motivation is to see what recent activity has been happening in Taiwan.

https://international.thenewslens.com/article/90599

https://international.thenewslens.com/article/91052 as examples.

The service I had looked at looked very much similar to this  -

www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/wordsinthenews/2014/09/140922_witn_ants.shtml

The only exception was it gave taiwan news all the time.

Comment: You can find live 24/7 news on YouTube from Taiwan in Chinese.

Comment: I updated my query a bit so it makes more sense than before.